# Dynamically changing font size of text without changing UILabel size

Tags: ios7, ios6, uilabel, uifont

I am developing an application in which I am having fixed size `UILabel` which may contain text of any size.
I need to resize font size without changing UILabel size.

Following is how I have tried to achieve this:

```
UILabel *errorMessageLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,50,300,30)];
    errorMessageLabel.lineBreakMode =NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    errorMessageLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    errorMessageLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
    errorMessageLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth=YES;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=7.0) {
        [errorMessageLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    }
    else{
        [errorMessageLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        errorMessageLabel.minimumFontSize=5.0;
    }
    [errorMessageLabel setTag:405];
    [errorMessageLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]];
    [backgroundView addSubview:errorMessageLabel];
```

Above solution works for iOS 7 but when I try to run this on iOS 6 it changes font size properly but sets text alignment to left ignoring its centre alignment.

Can any one please let me know how I can achieve this? I tried to search form other solution but nothing is working. I cannot change `UILabel`'s size

Answer (score 0):

```
errorMessageLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
errorMessageLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
errorMessageLabel.minimumFontSize = MIN_FONT_SIZE;
```

Comment: This I have already included in my `UILabel` but doesn't work for me. If I remove `errorMessageLabel.adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth=YES;` it does not resize text

Comment: numberOfLines property is set to 1.

Comment: text may need to display on multiple line at some instance